# Crash and Auto Reboot - Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, crash, kernel-panic

My MacBook Pro crashed and automatically rebooted. Even after I clean reinstalled OS X Mavericks, it is still crashing.Here is the crash log:

Anonymous UUID:       2CF421F9-E98E-0125-C067-D42BA1739E24

```
Thu Jan  9 03:15:28 2014
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff802c4a5d65): "VM_PAGE_QUEUES_REMOVE: unmarked page on Q"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-2422.1.72/osfmk/vm/vm_resident.c:3061
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff818ea737a0 : 0xffffff802c422f69 
0xffffff818ea73820 : 0xffffff802c4a5d65 
0xffffff818ea73870 : 0xffffff802c4a6e19 
0xffffff818ea738c0 : 0xffffff802c49d14f 
0xffffff818ea73be0 : 0xffffff802c7ffbe8 
0xffffff818ea73c30 : 0xffffff802c5d3658 
0xffffff818ea73cc0 : 0xffffff802c5c5084 
0xffffff818ea73d10 : 0xffffff7fac9ebab2 
0xffffff818ea73d60 : 0xffffff7fad29fbcd 
0xffffff818ea73dc0 : 0xffffff7fad2a765f 
0xffffff818ea73e00 : 0xffffff7fad27c02a 
0xffffff818ea73e30 : 0xffffff7fad888da5 
0xffffff818ea73e70 : 0xffffff7fad8880fd 
0xffffff818ea73ec0 : 0xffffff7fad88797b 
0xffffff818ea73f10 : 0xffffff7fad889fc7 
0xffffff818ea73f30 : 0xffffff802c8ac522 
0xffffff818ea73f80 : 0xffffff802c8ac5f7 
0xffffff818ea73fb0 : 0xffffff802c4d6aa7 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily(1.9)[9B09B065-7F11-3241-B194-B72E5C23548B]@0xffffff7fac9e8000->0xffffff7faca0cfff
         com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily(2.6)[EBAE52B6-A74C-39C9-8845-3F737C85DA9F]@0xffffff7fad278000->0xffffff7fad28dfff
         com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort(2.9.5)[35F30232-E2AA-3305-8B0E-4AF190925824]@0xffffff7fad880000->0xffffff7fad899fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily(2.6.0)[EBAE52B6-A74C-39C9-8845-3F737C85DA9F]@0xffffff7fad278000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.8)[447B4896-16FF-3616-95A2-1C516B2A1498]@0xffffff7facaba000
         com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage(2.4)[DE2724CF-D751-3AFF-AF39-7DB381393835]@0xffffff7fad29e000->0xffffff7fad2b4fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily(2.6.0)[EBAE52B6-A74C-39C9-8845-3F737C85DA9F]@0xffffff7fad278000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily(1.9)[9B09B065-7F11-3241-B194-B72E5C23548B]@0xffffff7fac9e8000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
13B42

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 1D9369E3-D0A5-31B6-8D16-BFFBBB390393
Kernel slide:     0x000000002c200000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff802c400000
System model name: MacBookPro9,2 (Mac-6F01561E16C75D06)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 11989019978458
last loaded kext at 7530741912725: com.apple.macos.driver.AppleUSBEthernetHost  7.0 (addr 0xffffff7fadaae000, size 28672)
last unloaded kext at 7794088344480: com.apple.macos.driver.AppleUSBEthernetHost    7.0 (addr 0xffffff7fadaae000, size 20480)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.nke.l2tp  1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBAttachedSCSI   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.13
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.14.11
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.2.0f6
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   8.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.5.3fc1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.5.3fc1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 1.0.10
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.3.5
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.2.0f6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.6.9b9
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   700.20.22
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 8.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.1.12
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  325.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.6.0
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    650.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.9
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.9.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   650.4.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   650.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 216.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   153
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   216.0.0
com.apple.nke.ppp   1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.7
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   91
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.5.3fc1
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.9.4fc11
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.14
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.2.0f6
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.2.0f6
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b4
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.5.3fc1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.5.3fc1
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   600.34
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    98.7.1
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.4.12
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.5.1d27
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.11d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.6d1
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    2.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    2.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 1.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 240.6
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  650.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   650.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  650.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    1.9.2
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 2.8.5
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 650.4.4
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 650.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  278.10
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 371.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  21
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.8
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
Model: MacBookPro9,2, BootROM MBP91.00D3.B09, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.5 GHz, 12 GB, SMC 2.2f44
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In, 1024 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x0198, 0x393955353432382D3034392E4130304C4620
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80CE, 0x4D34373142353237334448302D434B300000
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xF5), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.2.0f6 12982, 3 services, 15 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD ST500LM012, 500.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-8A8
USB Device: Backup+  RD
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 25.1
```

Comment: Did you preserve the users and applications on the drive? What was running when it crashed?

Comment: I am running time machine when this crash, but this may not be the reason of crash, I never use time machine before, still crash and reboot randomly.

Comment: So the only thing running when the computer crash is Finder and Time Machine is working away in the background? Nothing else?

Comment: no, chrome, mail, message and iterm2 also running, I am think if it is caused by memory, cause I add a 8 Gb memory to my system

Comment: two new crash after I ask this question, with different application running while crash, but the error message is same

Comment: Henry, the more you write the better. What applications and how long was the computer booted when it shut down on you. We need information to help

Comment: this is my working computer, so I open a lot application, what make crazy is I can't find any clue, both application running when crash and boot time, I have a lot application installed now but the first time crash after I do a clean reinstall have a few application, so the latter install application may have nothing to do with this issue. here is the list of application I install when first crash: `chrome, vox keynote numbers pages dash mplayerx alfred qq xcode`, and `mysql wget git` by `homebrew`

Comment: I would suggest going into Console.app in your Utilities folder and looking under the DiagnosticReports what applications are listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after buy change a new ram disk, never crash again